# Entity framework power tools installed but does not appear when i right clicked on project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, nuget

1. I install EntityFramework from NuGet package manager console
2. And then I go to  TOOLS > Extensions and Updates... and install
   EntityFramework Power Tools
3. I close Visual Studio 2017 and then I Open it again, I Right-Clicked on Project but there is no EntityFramework?

Please how can I fix this

Answer (score 0):

Please go to Tools-Extension and Update-Online, search and install [the Entity Framework 6 Power Tools Community Edition](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.EntityFramework6PowerToolsCommunityEdition).The previous extension "[Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 4](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EntityFrameworkTeam.EntityFrameworkPowerToolsBeta4)" is no longer being updated and maintained by the Entity Framework team. We recommend uninstalling it and using the Entity Framework 6 Power Tools Community Edition instead, which is maintained as an open source project by Erik Ejlskov Jensen and other members of the developer community.

After that, I tried to right click on an Entity Data Model .edmx file, the context menu function "**Generate Views**" is available as below:
[image]